# Minnesota Speeding Law

Tags: united-states, speeding, plea

I currently am 21 years old and I had a great memorial weekend that ended with me getting the blue lights... I received a speeding ticket for I was going 71 in a 55mph zone.. I currently have been looking into hiring a lawyer to see if I could get this off of my record, but I am still looking into it. My 2 questions are: is it worth the money to have a lawyer and see if they could help me get this ticket off my record? Since I am only 21 years old if I would get caught again it would definitely not help my case... I got quoted for one of the lawyers I talked with and they were asking a very steep price. I then again realize that breaking the law you have to pay a significant price.

Comment: It may be worth it if you can get "deferred adjudication", which basically means it doesn't appear on your record as long as you don't get another ticket within some time period. Deferred adjudication's actual meaning differs with location, so I would look into it for your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 4):

> is it worth the money to have a lawyer and see if they could help me
>   get this ticket off my record?

No. It is not worth the money and, absent very unusual circumstances, a lawyer is unlikely to be meaningfully more successful than dealing directly with the prosecutor in the case.

Your best, cost effective option is to contact the prosecutor's office to see if you could plea bargain it to a lesser charge (which is often possible, for example, by taking a driver's education course).

The main collateral disadvantage of a speeding ticket on your record is points on your driving record, which if there are enough of them, result in the temporary suspension of your driver's license, but those points expire after a few years.

Comment: I had a lawyer (about $200 if I remember) argue for (and get) deferred adjudication for a ticket, which meant no points and just a fine as long as I didn't get another ticket in 6 months. It was worth it just from an insurance savings standpoint. If that type of arrangement is possible in the OP's area, it may be worth pursuing especially if the OP has a clean record up to this point.

Comment: @Ron Beyer $200 is an amazing fee! I don't think I've ever seen someone charge less than $750-$1000 for something like this, but at that price, it might be worth it. Sounds like the fees in the 40 year old county bar association fee schedule I found in an old desk drawer at one of my first jobs (bar association price fixing is no longer permitted anyway) working with a Colorado firm that had been in continuous existence for longer than Colorado had been a state.